# Ubuntu upgraded to 15.10, now laptop won't reboot

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, 15.10

Samsung 400B laptop

Yesterday I left my laptop upgrading to 15.10 (I think it was Wily something) about half way through.

When I returned the laptop was hung with nothing on the screen.  Hard powered down by holding the power off key for a few seconds.

On reboot it tries to boot Ubuntu (I get the orange screen and two of the dots go orange) then says:

[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
....
Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen

Then nothing.

Anything I can do other than a rebuild from USB stick?

Comment: Having the same issue with Toshiba Satellite S75t.

Comment: I had to reinstall from USB stick